# Does anyone have any the images that sometimes accompany scriptures (e.g. in the Purāṇas)? Can you post them?

Tags: scripture, puranas, art

I heard some scriptures were found with attached images to help explain the text. Since then, I have always wanted to see some.

Comment: You can go through Gita Press books !

Comment: There are literally hundreds of such texts with accompanying pictures so it cannot be answered in a simple/concise answer on this site. Voting to close as too broad.